# Is it possible to share session state between asp.net aspx page making a call to an asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-session

**My Situation:**

I have 1 asp.net application with both aspx pages AND webservices

I make calls (using ajax) to the webservice from an aspx page - all within the same asp.net application!

**Here is my problem/question**
Is there any way to share the session state?

I.e. - the aspx page has a sessionID and the state is being maintained. When the call to the webservice is made, is there a way to automatically send the seesionID to the webservice and then be able to access the same session state from the webservice?

--

That would greatly simplify my work! :) Many thanks for your ideas!!

Comment: Is that an asmx based web service, or a WCF based web service? If using WCF you need to explicity request that asp.net session information etc is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the EnableSession property to the 
WebMethod attribute on your web service methods:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

Comment: Strange, did you try examining the cookies to verify that the correct session ID is sent?

Comment: he he, it did work!! THANKS JONAS!

ps, not sure why it did not work before, but i created everything from scratch and it now works. Superb!